# Memory release issue in C++

Tags: c++

We have code similar to the one below. We are trying to achieve RAII using a class called  MemRelease class. Now, FXOMemRelease is being used the way shown in sample.cc.

Is this OK to    use the obeject of FXOMemRelase like that ?   Most of the time I see that the destructor for MemRelease only gets called after MakeString() is completed. That is fine.
Will it be the case always ? We got a    memory issue and the truss output last pointed to the print statement in the    MemRelease class.

MemRelease.cpp

```
template<typename T>
MemRelease<T>::MemRelease(T* store, unsigned char array_yesno, short release_yesno)
        : ptr(store), array(array_yesno), release(release_yesno)
{
}


template<typename T>
T* MemRelease<T>::getStore()
{
        return (ptr);
}

template<typename T>
MemRelease<T>::~MemRelease()
{
        if (!release) return;
         if ( (array == 'Y') || (array == 'y') )
        {
                cout << "deleting array in MemRelease pid = " << getpid() << endl;
                delete [] ptr;
                ptr = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "deleting memory in MemRelease pid = " << getpid() <<  endl;
                delete ptr;
                ptr = NULL;
        }
}
```

Sample.cc:

```
char* MakeString(char* str)
{
   cout << "Entered MakeString\n";
   char* newstr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
   strcpy(newstr, str);
   return str;
}
int main()
{
   char *str = new char[10];
   strcpy(str, "jagan");
   char* newstr = MakeString(MemRelease<char>(str).getStore());

   getchar();
   delete newstr;
}
```

Comment: What are the default values of the constructor's parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most of the time I see that the destructor for MemRelease only gets called after MakeString() is completed. That is fine. Will it be the case always ?

Yes, always.  The temporary object stays valid until the assignment to `newstr` completes.

As afriza points out, we can't verify which destruction code is running because you haven't included the default values for the constructor's `array_yesno` and `release_yesno`.  BTW, there's a type called `bool` which should be used for yes/no values.

Comment: Afriza: :-) Yes I am aware of bool and string. The fact that it is a code that is lying around for sometime, I can't modify it now. Anyways, I got the answer for my question. Thanks.

Comment: No worries... working with old code can be painful... good luck!

Comment: Good luck for you. I am dealing with *NEW* codes but other programmers prefer to use new[], delete[], char*, and that sort of codes instead of std::string or boost::*   --sigh--

Answer (score 3):

instead of using `delete`, use `delete[]` because you are allocating memory using new[].

Since you are using C++, why don't you use `std::string` or `boost::scoped_ptr` `boost::scoped_array` and their friends?